# PostgreSQL multiple join issue

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join

Iam trying to create query with multiple JOINS, but Im receiving error message regarding syntax on second JOIN.

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INNER"
LINE 19:   INNER JOIN table2 AS jobinfo ON gaccess....
^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 418

Can you help me what am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT
  access.id,
  access.user_id,
  access.device_id,
  access.origin,
  access.creation_date
FROM
  table1 access
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      device_id,
      MAX (creation_date) AS creation_date
    FROM
      table1
    GROUP BY
      device_id
  ) gaccess ON access.device_id = gaccess.device_id
  AND access.creation_date = gaccess.creation_date;
  INNER JOIN 
    table2 AS jobinfo 
    ON gaccess.device_id = jobinfo.id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a type - before the last `INNER JOIN` there is `;` - you need to remove it.

```
SELECT access.id,
       access.user_id,
       access.device_id,
       access.origin,
       access.creation_date
FROM table1 access
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT device_id
          ,MAX(creation_date) AS creation_date
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY device_id
) gaccess 
    ON access.device_id = gaccess.device_id
    AND access.creation_date = gaccess.creation_date
INNER JOIN table2 AS jobinfo 
    ON gaccess.device_id = jobinfo.id;
```